# How to scrape tweets after July 2023?

Tags: web-scraping, twitter, extract, social-networking

Since Twitter's API is now impracticable for research and scrappers like SnScrape are not working because of the "login block" on the Twitter's search engine, there is a way to extract tweets that is actually working?

SnScrape is not working anymore: https://github.com/JustAnotherArchivist/snscrape/issues/996